# Storing a large matrix in postgresql and manipulating it in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, matrix, hdf5

I have a big matrix that I currently store in a specific table.
Each matrix row has a specific ID that is related to a different table. (That's the reason why I'm using RDBMS).
Currently, I'm using "JSONB" type column as the field for the row of the matrix (each matrix row contains 10000 columns).
So it looks like this -
ID , Different Table ID, Matrix Row (JSONB)

Now, I want to query this table to use the matrix. For example, iterating over batches of 500 rows of the matrix when the query should retrieve it already in a matrix form in python.

How can I do this?
Is there a better way of storing this matrix so I could manipulate it later?
Should I use HDF5 instead of SQL?

Comment: Could you post more information. What types are the cells, probably numeric? These 500 rows, how are they selected? Do you need all of them? Why Different Table ID? is that a foreign key? How is the different table related to the matrix row?

Comment: The matrix cells are numeric, all of the columns are selected, the other table ID is a foreign key that connects to a different table (one to one)

Comment: How many rows are typically inserted. Do you select a row because of a range, a single cell is to be found in, or do you need the rows because of a specific combination of numbers? Are the numbers distributed evenly? Are there many different values of the cell-numbers, if not, you can  think about using a bitmap-index.

Comment: @aschoerk There are more than 100000 rows. The rows are inserted also in batches. The numbers are not distributed evenly. The matrix represent a specific vector space - a trained model. I need to query it's in batches because I don't want to hold all of it in memory and I need to be able to use it for some numeric manipulations like using the dot product, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that currently you try to get "Different-Table-ID"s fitting to cell-content by letting postgres search the json-content. I presume that this search looks into 100000 records and does 10000 comparisions. If one search returns 500 records, that means, that 0.5 percent are the result of at least 1 Billion Integer or Float-comparisons (4 GByte) or in case of Doubles 8 GByte. If you don't want to keep that in the main memory, which nowadays would be quite easy, but want to use a SQL-DBMS:

It can be reasonable to define according to the following recommendations:

1. To use two tables

Table1: Row-ID, Different Table ID

Table2: Row-ID, Cell-Index (2 Bytes), CELL-Content(4 Bytes)

or

2. if the Row-ID is not important: just one Table

Different-Table-ID, Cell-Index (2 Bytes because smaller that 32000), Cell-Content (4 Bytes?)

think about defining these tables as https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html

if the order of the cells is not important, then drop the cell-index

3. If the cell-content-values do not vary too much, so if they might only contain values between 0 and 32000 you could also think about using a bitmap index.

In all cases, postgres should be able to avoid searching through all 100000 records to return the result. Over all it is important to look into the range, the different IDs and values might need. The smaller the range you can define from the beginning, the better postgres can optimize the searches. Everything is better than having to search 4 GByte+ Space for each query.

Comment: Well, I actually only query this table based on the foreign key and when I want to make some calculations with the matrix, then I query the table iteratively in batches. My main concern was to somehow convert the rows in the table to a (like a numpy) matrix in python to use for specific calculations (like the dot product, etc...). I will check out the sql clustering. Thanks